# What will be the velocity component in $x$-direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, velocity, vectors, collision

[image: In the figure, the particle is impacting on the surface at an angle theta and velocity V2 along y direction.]

In the figure, the particle is hitting the surface at an angle $\theta$ and velocity $V_2$ along the $y$ direction.
Is there a name for this velocity? Can it be called orthogonal velocity?

I have worked out the velocity to be as following:
$V_x = \frac{V_2}{\cot(\theta)}$.

Kindly guide me with this.

Comment: While the question "is there a name for this velocity" is perfectly legitimate (as a conceptual question), the rest isn't, as it is a homework-style question. Please ask about a specific conceptual problem at a step of your calculations that is giving you trouble and show your work to get to the solution.

Comment: @heather I have removed the rest part of the question.  It is the name of the velocity component that I am interested in knowing.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your figure. What is "y,2 /x,1"? Also, is $v_2$ in the figure meant to be the velocity vector shown or something else? Usually in this situation you would chose coordinates such that $x$ is  parallel to the surface and $y$ perpendicular (or vice versa). I don't think there is a special name for the velocity component that is perpendicular to the surface. Calling it "orthogonal velocity (component)" seems reasonable and should be understood.

Comment: @rcty okay, I will withdraw my close vote then. +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would describe the direction of $V_2$ as **oblique**, in contrast to **normal** (perpendicular to the surface) or **glancing/grazing** (almost parallel to the surface). The same terminology is used for light rays.

Well that is your *conceptual* question answered, so no more guidance is needed - ok?